# Iup Lua callback -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: lua, iup

I'm using Lua 5.1 with IUP 3.5, and trying to use a list callback to populate an Address list depending on the Place selected. (The list is an editbox, so I will need to handle that in due course, but let us deal with the basics first). I've clearly got a fundamental misunderstanding of how to do this.

The code:

```
function MakeAnIupBox
    --make some more elements here
    listPlace = iup.list{}
    listPlace.sort = "YES"
    listPlace.dropdown = "YES" 
    --populate the list here
    --now handle callbacks
    listPlace.action = function(self) PlaceAction(text, item,  state) end
end

function PlaceAction(text, item, state)
    listAddress.REMOVEITEM = "ALL"
    if state == 1 then -- a place has been selected
    --code here to populate the Addresses list
    end
end
```

The [iup documentation](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/elem/iuplist.html) describes the action callback for a list as

> ih:action(text: string, item, state: number) -> (ret: number) [in Lua]

However, when I run this code I get:

- text -- looks like some sort of metatable
- item, state -- both nil

I've also tried coding the callback as

```
function MakeAnIupBox
    --make some more elements here
    listPlace = iup.list{}
    listPlace.sort = "YES"
    listPlace.dropdown = "YES" 
    --populate the list here
end
function listPlace:action (text, item, state)
    listAddress.REMOVEITEM = "ALL"
    if state == 1 then -- a place has been selected
        --code here to populate the Addresses list
    end
end
```

but that fails to run: the error is `attempt to index global 'listPlace' (a nil value)`

I'd prefer not to embed the callback in "MakeAnIupBox" because I'm hoping to make it (and the other associated callbacks) a resuable component in several Lua programmes that all process similar datasets but from different UIs.

Comment: What does iup.list{} return?

Comment: @Phins an empty iup List control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the suggestion of Antonio Scuri which was not totally explicit, I have worked out that the code needs to read:

```
function MakeAnIupBox
    --make some more elements here
    listPlace = iup.list{}
    listPlace.sort = "YES"
    listPlace.dropdown = "YES" 
    --populate the list here
    --now handle callbacks
    listPlace.action = function(self, text, item, state) PlaceAction(listPlace, text, item,  state) end
end

function PlaceAction(ih, text, item, state)
    listAddress.REMOVEITEM = "ALL"
    if state == 1 then -- a place has been selected
    --code here to populate the Addresses list
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to embed the callback function inside your function, you can define it before and later assign it to your specified destination.

```
function Callback(self, a, b)
   -- do your work ...
end

function CallbackUser1()
    targetTable = { }
    targetTable.entry = Callback
end

function CallbackUser2()
    otherTargetTable = { }
    otherTargetTable.entry = Callback
end
```

This solution needs the arguments to be always the same.

**Note:** All following definitions are identical

```
function Table:func(a, b) ... end
function Table.func(self, a, b) ... end
Table.func = function(self, a, b) ... end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Lua usage.

In the first case, remember that this:

```
function ih:action(text, item, state)
```

translates into this:

```
function action(ih, text, item, state)
```

So it is missing the ih parameter.

In the second case, listCase exists only after MakeAnIupBox is called. You can solve that by declaring the function inside the MakeAnIupBox scope.

Comment: Have edited the question to explain why I'd prefer not to embed the callback function inside the MakeAnIUPbox function.

Comment: It's actually `function ih.action(self, text, item, state)` -- which is quite different from `function action(ih, text, item, state)`!